# how to get the file name?

Tags: python, django

please help to get the file name.

I uploaded the images to the database. model:

```
class AvtoPark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='avtos/static/uploads/')

    @classmethod
    def get_all_entries(self):
        return self.objects.all()
```

field "IMAGE" contains addresses like:

```
avtos/static/uploads/img1_b.png
```

template I bring them as follows:

```
{% for entrie in all_entries_avtopark %}
    {{ entrie.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

the result is displayed:

```
avtos/static/uploads/img1_b.png
```

I need to display:

```
img1_b.png
```

Comment: You're using a classmethod but using self, it should be cls.

Comment: did you try to look at the doc for `os.path` ?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian : that's just a convention

Comment: @njzk2 I know its a convention, but it's best to follow this convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model add this:

```
import os
...

class AVTPark(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def image_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name)
```

In your template:

```
{% for entrie in all_entries_avtopark %}
    {{ entrie.image_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited :
You can create your own method in your models.py class.

```
class AvtoPark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='avtos/static/uploads/')

    @classmethod
    def get_all_entries(self):
        return self.objects.all()

    def get_image_name(self):
        # here you can apply your logic what you want to display 
        # try to do same like below i am doing 
        return str(self.image.url).split('/')[-1]
```

while in template you can call directly like :

```
{% for entrie in all_entries_avtopark %}
    {{ entrie.get_image_name( }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not worked/ displayed: avtos/static/uploads/img1_b.png
please tell me where it is described in the documentation